# Unexpected indentation of "note" directives

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have three `..note::` style directives in RST, when I build them locally on my PC the formatting on the HTML looks fine and the directives are discretely stacked above each other. When it is built on my production server, the notes are indented into one another. Example of code and the formatting from the production HTML.

```
.. note::

   Text 1

.. note::
   
   Text 2

.. important::

   Text 3
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Link to RST Indentation Issue Image of HTML Formatting]

I omitted my actual text from the directives, but the lines don't wrap so the formatting is all on the same line with what I think is the correct indentation. Other note directives are fine, it's just when two notes follow each other.

I tried to add `|` line breaks on either side of the directives and also pulling the indentation back to top level, i.e. no spacing to the left of the `..`.

Comment: Compare the versions of all packages installed locally and on the server, and make sure the server matches your local packages.

Comment: This looks a lot like the second "note" and "important" admonitions are nested (i.e. indented before they reach the parser) in the version that produces the shown output. You may experiment with a dummy paragraph inbetween to see whether it is indeed related to two "note"s in a row. Maybe it is also some Sphinx extension that messes things up.